# interaction.options.getUser('user') not work discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `userinfo` command in `discord.js` v14. On v13, I had the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'userinfo',
    aliases: 'userinfo, ui, useri',
    categorie: 'Information',
    permissions: '',
    id: '1028260314694823936',
    description: ' Affiche des informations sur un utilisateur.',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'user',
            nameLocalizations: { fr: 'utilisateur'},
            description: 'De quel utilisateur voulez vous voir les informations ?',
            type: '6',
        }
    ],
    async execute(interaction, client, args) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user') || interaction.user
```

But the problem is that with `discord.js` v14 `interaction.options.getUser('user')` does not work. The error I get is:

```js
interaction.options.getUser is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

In v14, you can't declare the type of option using strings. You will have to use enums instead. To do that, you can import [`ApplicationCommandOptionType`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType), and then use it. The various options are:

1. [`ApplicationCommandOptionType.String`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType#String)
2. [`ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType#Number)
3. [`ApplicationCommandOptionType.Channel`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType#Channel)
4. [`ApplicationCommandOptionType.User`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType#User) etc.

Your fixed code would look like this:

```js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js")
// ...
    options: [
        {
            name: 'user',
            nameLocalizations: { fr: 'utilisateur'},
            description: 'De quel utilisateur voulez vous voir les informations ?',
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
        }
    ]
```

To learn more, you can go here => [ApplicationCommandOptionType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType)

Comment: The number "6" is work. https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-type  and I always get the error.

Comment: I'm just speaking from experience here. Even I had a v14 bot and this method worked for me

Comment: I have tried update discord.js but it didn't do anything

Comment: Have you tried the method in the answer?

Comment: I have tried the method

Comment: Is there any error coming up?

Comment: Yes the error is : ``interaction.options.getUser is not a function``

Comment: Can you show the command handler file?

Comment: The handler : https://pastebin.com/wjp0Hx4

Comment: I found the error I had put ``interaction, client, args`` when it was necessary to put: ``client, interaction, args``...

Comment: Oh ok . Glad to hear that